# How to estimate the age of players correctly?

Tags: distributions, sampling, unbiased-estimator, selection-bias

I have the data of players active on a gaming console and the playtime hours corresponding to the games they have played and their age. I want to analyze the top (say 10) games that the people between age 18-24 have played. However, I know that the reported age on the gaming console is highly unreliable. Is there anyway we could reduce the unreliability and reach a (nearly) fair estimation? Please let me know if additional information is required for answering this question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some reliable, independent ground truth?

Comment: Could you please give me examples of "ground truths"?

Comment: Yes: those would be people whose ages you are more certain about.  Without some such information, you're purely guessing.

Comment: Sorry for not being able to reply earlier @whuber, I thought about this and I don't think we have any source for ground truth yet. What are the other ways to make an estimated guess? Please let me know if you think additional info on this would be subservient for you to suggest a solution

Comment: You can make an "estimated guess" using a Ouija board, a random number generator, an oracle, or whatever.  You just won't have any basis to support any claims concerning how accurate your guessing might be.